# CQ5 Blue print Roll Out Changes

Tags: aem, multisite

I create a page in blue print and rolling it out. Its getting reflected in live copies.
Similarly i delete a page from blue print(which is present both in blue print as well as in live copy and they are in sync) and rolling out. The page in the live copy didn't get deleted, but it shows the message page is deleted in blue print, is this the way Cq blue print works?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the roll config you have chosen. The standard roll out config wouldn't cascade delete function to live copy pages. Try using the OOTB push on modify roll out config, i'm guessing this config cascades page deletion to the live copy.

Comment: Thank You for the Answer. With OOTB i can see the deletion of pages from Live copy also

Comment: While using OOTB push on modify roll out config along with default config .Roll out for subpages is not working and also the msm control center is not showing the proper legends when a page is modified in blue print. Have you ever faced similar kind of issues